# Drop down in the website not working after deployment

Tags: html, r, deployment, r-markdown, netlify

I have configured a website using R markdown (static HTML). The website was configured a few years ago, and the YAML structure below worked fine to create a drop down after deploying the site.

```
  name: "personal-website"
  output_dir: "."
  title: "Personal Website"
  left:
    - text: "Home"
      href: index.html
    - text: "About Me"
      href: a.html 
    - text: "Projects" 
      menu: 
        - text: "Class Projects"
        - text: "P1"
          href: a.html
        - text: "---------"
        - text: "Personal Projects"
        - text: "P2" 
          href: a.html
output:
  html_document:
    theme: flatly
    css: style.css
```

Problem statement:

I uploaded new projects then redeployed the site, now the index.html that is created locally shows the desired dropdown structure, but post deployment, I cannot use a mouse click to open the drop down. Can you help me figure out if the problem is with my HTML structure, or the tool I am using for deployment? (I am deploying it via Netlify).

I have created a dummy example here:

https://demoamasite.netlify.app/

**HTML in question:**

```css
img {
  height: 500px;
  width: 75%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<li class="dropdown">
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    Projects

    <span class="caret"></span>
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li class="dropdown-header">Class Projects</li>
    <li>
      <a href="a.html">P1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li class="dropdown-header">Personal Projects</li>
    <li>
      <a href="a.html">P2</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

I have also drilled down to this issue with HTML inspection:

- the "dropdown" class doesn't get toggled to "dropdown open" after a mouse click.

Multiple mouse clicks on "Projects". Nothing happens:
[image]

I edited the HTML manually to "dropdown open" and that opens the dropdown:

[image]

Comment: Please share your HTML and CSS in the question itself as text; see [mcve] for more info. A link to a live website is not sufficient for us to debug or help you.

Comment: Tyler, I have added html block to the original question, thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Thanks--please also add your CSS--when you edit your question, click the "edit the above snippet" link below the runnable Stack Snippet I converted your HTML to. That will let you open the Snippet editor window and paste your CSS directly into a special section just for that. That will let us run a demo of your code here on-site.

Comment: @TylerH - Thank you once again for your help, I appreciate it. I have added the css as you asked(which is not much, just a custom image size specification). Since rmarkdown::render_site() does all the work of converting markdown to html, I do not know where the css is specified.

Comment: I'm adding the R tag because it seems like this is an issue with the backend side of things that generate interactive aspects--if the dropdown should appear on click, that's not really HTML or CSS doing that, but JavaScript (or whatever R uses for R-Markdown sites). Hopefully someone following the R tag will be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up copying everything over manually to a new project, and afterwards everything worked fine. I wonder what had caused it. Since I started working on this project after a 2 year gap - I had updated R markdown on my local machine. Still, I needed to create a new project to get things to work as expected.